# insert data in database and show same data after insert without refresh page(call data after insert of database)

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want insert some of data in database by ajax call ($.ajax()) and generation tracking code by a code php  and with others data it insert in database  . how after (upon) insert in database, displaying to user it tracking code ? (Without Refresh Page)

With respect
my code:

```
$('.insert').live('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
        //alert(dataObj)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'insert_customers',
            data: dataObj,
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                //alert(idname)
                    $('.result').hide().fadeIn('slow').html("<div class='message'>Your information was successfully. your tracking code is : '+$tracking' </div>"); 
            },
                "error": function (x, y, z) {
                    // callback to run if an error occurs
                    alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
                }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: You aren't giving us enough code to help you. We don't know what, if anything, you are returning from your "success" call. Currently, your function for "success" doesn't handle any parameters, so anything returned from the ajax call will just evaporate.

Comment: .insert is for send data in database, for getting data (tracking  code) of database after insert, what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send back data to the client (either html or objects) and use the data in the success function. To do so you use whatever print method that your server language uses (ie. if php use echo, perl print, etc) To print a content header and the information (like you would on a normal request for a web page. I would sugesst sending a content header of `Content-type:application/json` and format your data back as `{"tracking":trackingVar}` Then in your success function define it as:

```
success: function(data) {
    //alert(idname)
    $('.result').hide().fadeIn('slow').html("<div class='message'>Your information was successfully. your tracking code is : " + data.tracking + " </div>"); 
},
```

Comment: .insert is for send data in database, for getting data (tracking  code) of database after insert, what do i do?

Comment: Once you insert send back the tracking code using the same method of printing that you use for a web page. What server-side language are you using? You will use the success function for the ajax call on the insert to receive the data from the server and display to the user.

Comment: Ok so after your code finishes the DB stuff, in your PHP code you should be able to echo "Content-type: application/json\n"; echo "{'tracking':$tracking}; Where $tracking is the tracking variable that you have assigned that particular transaction. Then in the JS update your success function to the one above.